# FairPlay > SPC > streamingContentKeyRequestData > App Identifier

Tags: http-live-streaming, apple-tv, fairplay

Can someone please clarify what is 'appIdentifier' in below function?

func streamingContentKeyRequestData(forApp appIdentifier: Data, contentIdentifier: Data, options: [String : Any]? = nil) throws -> Data

Is it something bundled within the Apple TV app or do we need to get it from server? Please explain it with example.

Answer (score 1):

appIdentifier should be the certificate used to identify the application provider assigned by Apple.

If you look at the sample application in the sdk, you will see that it downloads the certificate from the server, because presumably it could change if there is an update from Apple.

Comment: Do you know how can I obtain this certificate from Apple?

Comment: You request the certificate at this page: https://developer.apple.com/contact/fps/  you need to have a developer account to do so.

Comment: Thanks @dar for pointing this out. Could you tell me what the `contentIdentifier` is for? The manual says: "An opaque identifier for the content. The value of this identifier depends on the particular system used to provide the decryption key.".

Comment: @palme the contentIdentifier is the id your system uses to identify a particular video.  Presumably you would assign a different key for each video, so you need a way to look up which key to use.

Comment: OK this is would I thought too. Thanks for the clarification!